# read private.key with fs.readFileSync, nvalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation

Tags: javascript, fs

Hi i try to read my private key with fs.readFileSync but always get this error:

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
> ^^^^^^

> SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation

and i don't understand why because i was quiet sure in the past it worked.

Fy function is this:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const RSA_PRIVATE_KEY = fs.readFileSync('private.key', 'utf-8');
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: are those 2 lines really all there is? did the syntax error point to any part in your code?

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I am running into the same issue but can't seem to find a clear answer. Was it just your import path that was problematic? Looking at your post, it appears that the import is working properly, so your response to the initial question is a bit unclear

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into the same issue, it turns out that relative paths are a bit dodgy with filesync. I was able to resolve it by adding the following code to my call to fs.readfilesync.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../../private.pem'), 'utf8');
```

__dirname returns the path to the current file's directory. By combining this with our relative path, we can create the full file path.

The other answer to this question suggests you import the file and then try to reference it in readfilesync; however, I found this created additional problems and didn't solve the issue.